# Find the polynomial function

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Anybody knows how to find the polynomial function with evaluated values, where if the degree is $n$ I have $n+1$ values of the function like $f(0) = a_0, f(1) = a_1, \ldots, f(n) = a_n$.

Comment: Lagrange interpolation.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html

Comment: its essentially equivalent to solving system of $n+1$ linear equations

Comment: I thought that, but I can't to solve how to represent the constant with the $f(k) = a_k$

Answer (score 2):

Use $$p_i(x)=\frac {\prod_{i\neq j} (x-x_i)} {\prod_{i\neq j} (x_j - x_i)}$$ as a basis for the vector space, and notice that $p_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$.